# Multiple category RSS feeds

Tags: rss, feed

Taken from [WordPress Feeds](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds):

> You can include posts from one of multiple categories or tags in a
>   feed by comma-separating their values. For example:
>
> http://www.example.com/category/cat1,cat2/feed
>
> You can include posts from all of multiple categories or tags in a
>   feed by adding to the end of the link. For example:
>
> http://www.example.com/category/cat1/category/cat2/feed

I understand the 2nd feed will include posts from both cat1 and cat2. The 1st feed looks, to me at least, as though it will do exactly the same. How do these feed URLs differ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
http://www.example.com/category/cat1,cat2/feed
```

will include posts belonging to `cat1` *OR* `cat2`, while

```
http://www.example.com/category/cat1/category/cat2/feed
```

will include posts belonging to both `cat1` *AND* `cat2` simultaneously. **See the update below!**

In the following example, the first RSS will include all posts, while the second – `Post 3` and `Post 4` only.

```
Category 1
|- Post 1
|- Post 2
|- Post 3
|- Post 4

Category 2
|- Post 3
|- Post 4
|- Post 5
|- Post 6
```

**Updated!**

Surprisingly, in spite of WordPress Codex [instructions on finding RSS feed URL](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds#Categories_and_Tags), the second feed URL shows only the last category mentioned in URL. The right formed URL for `cat1` *AND* `cat2` will look as follows:

```
http://www.example.com/category/cat1+cat2/feed
```

Thanks @birgire for drawing my attention to this.

Comment: The second AND example only fetched cat2 on my install, did that work for you as expected? Maybe it's just my install that's not working ;-)

Comment: No, it does not work. I should test it before posting. I've edited the answer.

Comment: @henrywright, please see the edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for updating, and thanks to @birgire for noticing the problem.